# jQuery - re-execute a function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a pretty unique situation where I need a bunch of jQuery code to re-execute on a button click. The added complications are:

- I can't allow the browser window to refresh
- All the code is within a setTimeout() parameter - not sure if this really matters

I can't wrap the code inside a click event as it needs to run automatically on first opening or refresh of the page. To add a bit of context I've mocked up the following:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
     // all the scripts that need to run
 }, 2500);

 $('.btn').click(function() {
     // re-run the above code without refreshing window or browser
 });
```

Is there a way to re-run the code on a button click in this context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a reusable jquery click function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783420/how-to-write-a-reusable-jquery-click-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a fairly common issue.

Make a function that contains the code you need to run in both places, and call the function from the setTimeout and onclick handler:

```
function someCode () {
    // Your code here
} 

setTimeout (someCode, 2500);

$('.btn').click(someCode);
```

When in doubt, make a function.

Answer (score 2):

put all your code that needs running in a function of its own and call the function in both places

```
function myFunc()
{
    // all the scripts that need to run
}

setTimeout(function() {
     myFunc();
 }, 2500);

 $('.btn').click(function() {
     myFunc();
 });
```

Comment: You don't actually need to wrap `myFunc` in a function, you can simply pass in the function by reference to both the timeout and the click functions.

Comment: Had to choose the answer that came first but this is also a perfect solution so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the functions within a variable which can be called in both the `setTimeout()` and also on a `click()` event

```js
var nameOfFunction = function() {
  console.log('Hello World!');
}
setTimeout(nameOfFunction, 2500);

 $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     nameOfFunction();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects are passed by reference so you can just reference the function by name in each of the callacks.

```js
function myFunc(){
  // all the scripts that need to run
}

setTimeout(myFunc, 2500)

$('.btn').click(myFunc)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```