# Store a javascript function in a variable and call manually

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, dom-events

I want to store the function reference in a variable and re use it by calling wherever required. Suppose I have a click bound function like this:

```
var clickEvent = $('#mode').click(function () {
   alert("Hello");
});
```

And I want to reuse it like this:

```
//call somewhere
clickEvent();
```

But it is showing an error clickEvent is not a function, why ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. If you want to set a eventListener, you can do that directly. Otherwise, use `function clickEvent()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a reusable jquery click function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783420/how-to-write-a-reusable-jquery-click-function)

Comment: `.click()` doesn't return a function, it returns the jQuery object it was called on, so they can be chained. What are you expecting `clickEvent()` to do?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the snippet inside a function , but even in that case the click event won't be triggered.

```js
var x = function() {
  $('#mode').click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  });
   // on call of this function click event will
  $("#mode").trigger('click')
}
x()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mode"> Click</button>
```

With only javascript

```js
var x = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('mode')
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('clicked')
  })
  el.click();
}
x()
```

```html
<button id="mode"> Click</button>
```

Comment: dont know @brk I haven't... thanks but can I do the same in javascript without jquery?

Comment: can u please add javascript as well

Comment: @subhajit have added new snippet with only js

Answer (score 0):

`$('#mode').click(...)` doesn't return a function, it returns the value of `$('#mode')` so that you can chain method, e.g. `$('#mode').click(...).change(...)`.

If you want a name for the handler function, define it separately:

```
function clickEvent() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

and then use it in the event binding:

```
$("#mode").click(clickEvent);
```

or call it directly:

```
clickEvent();
```